# Como fazer o Nginx fornecer conteúdo pré compactado?

Tags: nginx, gzip

Já habilitei o modulo [HttpGzipStaticModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipStaticModule), e defini a variável

```
gzip_static on;
```

Mas nos cabeçalhos de resposta de uma requisição GET não aparece

```
Content-Encoding    gzip
```

Comment: você enviou o cabeçalho ```Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate```?

Comment: sim estou recebendo `Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch`, verifiquei isso usando o firebug no firefox e as ferramentas para desenvolvedores do chrome

Comment: Se os arquivos estão possuem extensão ```.gz```, os cabeçalhos estão certos e o você já reiniciou o nginx, tudo deveria funcionar. Pra ajudar mais do que isso, só olhando os arquivos de configurações, logs e a saída do comando ```curl -v -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch" "URL_destino"```, em que o ```-v``` pede a saída verbosa e o ```-H``` envia o cabeçalho como parâmetro.

Comment: Não estou usando arquivos em .gz, apenas hospedando imagens png, jpg e gif

Comment: O link do módulo que você adicionou acima, diz que é necessário que os arquivos compactados estejam no mesmo diretório dos não-compactados e possuam extensão `.gz`. Talvez o que você esteja procurando seja o [HttpGzipModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpGzipModule) que faz a compactação no momento da requisição. Contudo, acredito que não faça sentido adicionar mais essa compactação em imagens, dado que esse tipo de arquivo já possui compactação própria.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Olha, acho que você confundiu de módulo. O HttpGzipStaticModule serve arquivos *pré-compactados* se eles existirem. Ou seja, se você tem `image.png` e `image.png.gz` e o cliente pede `image.png`, o módulo vai servir o `image.png.gz` no lugar. Quem faz a compressão é você.

Para compactar na hora, use o [NginxHttpGzipModule](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html). Note, no entanto, que por default ele comprime só `text/html`. Preste atenção nos parâmetros desse módulo para configurar direito.

Outra coisa: imagens já são pré-compactadas em sua grande maioria (e em todos os casos que você citou). Tentar compactá-las vai ser inútil. Existem algumas ferramentas que podem ajudar, como OptiPNG (veja [esse artigo](http://www.creativebloq.com/design/image-compression-tools-1132865) com uma lista). O Google também tem [dicas a respeito](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-images). Mas ativar o gzip vai ser inútil.

Comment: No final das contas acabei criando uma versão compactada de cada arquivo (.gz), pois lembrei que tenho outros arquivos de texto como .css .js .html

Answer (score 1):

Bom, eu compacto os arquivos assim que subo as atualizações do site e executo este script que gera os ***.gz** que o NGINX vai buscar.

```java
#! /bin/bash

FILETYPES=( "*.woff" "*.css" "*.jpg" "*.jpeg" "*.gif" "*.png" "*.js"  )
# specify a list of directories to check recursively
DIRECTORIES="/www/siteX/static/"

for currentdir in $DIRECTORIES
do
   for i in "${FILETYPES[@]}"
   do
      find $currentdir -iname "$i" -exec bash -c 'PLAINFILE={};GZIPPEDFILE={}.gz; \
         if [ -e $GZIPPEDFILE ]; \
         then   if [ `stat --printf=%Y $PLAINFILE` -gt `stat --printf=%Y $GZIPPEDFILE` ]; \
                then    echo "$GZIPPEDFILE antigo, atualizando"; \
                        gzip -9 -f -c $PLAINFILE > $GZIPPEDFILE; \
                 fi; \
         else echo "$GZIPPEDFILE estah faltando, criando..."; \
              gzip -9 -c $PLAINFILE > $GZIPPEDFILE; \
         fi' \;
  done
done
```